# Rails 4 - How can I map 2 columns of a Model to another column of another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to map 2 columns of the same model (`dev_status` and `test_planning_status`) to another model's column (`Status.name`) and in the `UserStory` form I want to have a dropdown with values from `Status` table

I have tried something like this but unable to figure out

Status model is like this

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dev_status, :class_name => 'UserStory', :foreign_key => 'dev_status_id'
  has_many :test_planning_status, :class_name => 'UserStory', :foreign_key => 'test_planning_status_id'
end
```

Currently I have this in models/UserStory

```
class UserStory < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :us_number, presence: true
validates :team_id, presence: true
validates :dev_status,  presence:true
validates :test_status,  presence:true
belongs_to :team
```

CreateUserStories migration is

```
class CreateUserStories < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     create_table :user_stories do |t|
     t.string :us_number
     t.references :team
     t.string :dev_status
     t.string :test_planning_status
     t.integer :tc_count
     t.timestamps null: false
  end
  add_foreign_key :user_stories, :pod
end
```

My UserStoryController params is

```
def user_story_params
  params.require(:user_story).permit(:us_number, :team_id, :dev_status, :test_planning_status)
end
```

UserStory _form is

```
<%= f.label :dev_status,'Dev Status' %>
    <%= f.select :status, Status.all.map {|u|[u.status, u.id]}, 
                                      {include_blank: true} %>

<%= f.label :test_planning_status, 'Test Planning Status' %>
    <%= f.select :status, Status.all.map {|u|[u.status, u.id]}, 
                                      {include_blank: true} %>
```

Comment: clarify the question please

Comment: Does status have to be its own model or can they predefined? (i.e. is adding more status codes a user feature?)

Comment: I want to have Status as a separate Model so that if there are more status it can be added through Admin console later.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko - I want to use the Status model values for populating dev_status and test_status while creating the UserStory record and so for this I am trying to use references, but I am unable to get this working, may be there is another way than what I am planning above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal should be to call `UserStory.dev_status.name` to get the `dev_status` name, and `UserStory.test_planning_status.name` to get the `test_planning_status` name.

1. Your migration should be creating columns `dev_status_id` (not `dev_status`) and `test_planning_status_id` (not `test_planning_status`).

   Use `t.references` or `t.belongs_to` in your future migrations.
2. Above columns should be **integers**, not strings.
3. You need to specify `belongs_to` on the `UserStory` object for your status fields.

   ```
   belongs_to :dev_status, class_name: 'Status'
   belongs_to :test_planning_status, class_name: 'Status'
   ```
4. Change

   `validates :test_status, presence:true`

   to

   `validates :test_planning_status, presence:true`
5. The two `f.select :status` in your form need to be changed to `f.select :test_planning_status` and `f.select :dev_status`

That should get you pointed in the right direction. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a standard [`has_many` relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association)::

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
   # columns id | name | value | other | information | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :user_stories
end

class UserStory < ActiveRecord::Base
   # columns id | title | value | dev_status_id | test_planner_status | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :dev_status, class_name: :status
   belongs_to :test_planning_status, class_name: :status
end
```

This would give you the ability to access the following:

```
#app/controllers/statuses_controller.rb
class UserStoriesController < ActionController::Base
   def show
      @story = UserStory.find params[:id]
      #@story.dev_status = gives you dev's details, with status value from Status table
   end
end
```

If you wanted to avoid the [law of demeter](http://samurails.com/tutorial/rails-delegate-dont-break-the-law-of-demeter/) (IE only have one point to access your data), you'll want to use the `delegate` method:

```
#app/models/user_story.rb
Class UserStory < ActiveRecord::Base
    delegate :name to: :dev_status, prefix: true
    # this will allow you to call @user.dev_status_name
end
```

If you then wanted to have statuses changed, you'll be able to use the [`collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) helper to get it working with the `Status` objects:

```
#app/views/user_stories/edit.html.erb
...
<%= f.collection_select :dev_status_id, Status.all, :id, :name, prompt: true %>
<%= f.collection_select :test_planner_status, Status.all, :id, :name, prompt: true %>
```

--

**ActiveRecord**

[image]

You must remember that **models are *built***, they are just classes. Rails uses an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) ([ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)) to pull data to populate these classes.

Many people become confused about how `models` fit into the Rails ecosystem. A model is made of "attributes", which you have to populate, either manually or through the Rails ORM API. IE your `User` model could have the following:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def will_you_marry_me?
       "no"
    end
end

#app/views/application.html.erb
Will the user marry? 
<%= @user.will_you_marry_me? %>
```

When you talk about "mapping" columns, what you're really asking is how to call a different *table's* data to attributes in your model class. For example, if you have `User` class, how to populate `@user.birthday` with data from `profiles` table etc.

The answer to that is to use the relational structure of ActiveRecord. Relational databases simply work with [`foreign_keys`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) to load data from other tables. For example, you could have `profiles` table with `user_id` to get information about a specific user (see the image above).

ActiveRecord makes the process of loading "other table" data very simple. By using the relationships in the API, you can populate data with the likes of `has_many` etc.